# Monitor shows 'no signal' after Nvidia driver installation (ubuntu 12.04 amd64)

Tags: drivers, nvidia, hardware

I use Ubuntu 12.04 amd64
The last thing I see before this message is ubuntu boot splash screen.

The hardware configuration is:

- Gigabyte 970a-ud3 motherboard
- AMD Phenom II X4 975 processor
- 8 GB RAM
- NVIDIA Corporation GT200 [GeForce GTX 260]

I've tried to remove xorg.conf, but nothing have changed. And now I have no idea about what should I do to make it work.

Here's an excerpt from /var/log/Xorg.0.log that seems to make sense.

```
[    13.956] (==) Matched nvidia as autoconfigured driver 0
[    13.956] (==) Matched nouveau as autoconfigured driver 1
[    13.956] (==) Matched nv as autoconfigured driver 2
[    13.956] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 3
[    13.956] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 4
[    13.956] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
[    13.956] (II) LoadModule: "nvidia"
[    13.956] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module nvidia
[    13.956] (II) UnloadModule: "nvidia"
[    13.956] (II) Unloading nvidia
[    13.956] (EE) Failed to load module "nvidia" (module does not exist, 0)
[    13.956] (II) LoadModule: "nouveau"
[    13.957] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/nouveau_drv.so
[    13.957] (II) Module nouveau: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    13.957]    compiled for 1.11.3, module version = 0.0.16
[    13.957]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    13.957]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 11.0
[    13.957] (II) LoadModule: "nv"
[    13.957] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module nv
[    13.957] (II) UnloadModule: "nv"
[    13.957] (II) Unloading nv
[    13.957] (EE) Failed to load module "nv" (module does not exist, 0)
[    13.957] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
[    13.957] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vesa_drv.so
[    13.957] (II) Module vesa: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    13.957]    compiled for 1.11.3, module version = 2.3.0
[    13.957]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    13.957]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 11.0
[    13.957] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[    13.957] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
[    13.957] (II) Module fbdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    13.957]    compiled for 1.11.3, module version = 0.4.2
[    13.957]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 11.0
[    13.957] (==) Matched nvidia as autoconfigured driver 0
[    13.957] (==) Matched nouveau as autoconfigured driver 1
[    13.957] (==) Matched nv as autoconfigured driver 2
[    13.957] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 3
[    13.957] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 4
[    13.957] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
[    13.957] (II) LoadModule: "nvidia"
[    13.958] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module nvidia
[    13.958] (II) UnloadModule: "nvidia"
[    13.958] (II) Unloading nvidia
[    13.958] (EE) Failed to load module "nvidia" (module does not exist, 0)
[    13.958] (II) LoadModule: "nouveau"
[    13.958] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/nouveau_drv.so
[    13.958] (II) Module nouveau: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    13.958]    compiled for 1.11.3, module version = 0.0.16
[    13.958]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    13.958]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 11.0
[    13.958] (II) UnloadModule: "nouveau"
[    13.958] (II) Unloading nouveau
[    13.958] (II) Failed to load module "nouveau" (already loaded, 0)
[    13.958] (II) LoadModule: "nv"
[    13.958] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module nv
[    13.958] (II) UnloadModule: "nv"
[    13.958] (II) Unloading nv
[    13.958] (EE) Failed to load module "nv" (module does not exist, 0)
[    13.958] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
```

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you running?  What version of the nVidia driver did you install? Support for your hardware was added in 280.13 so you will need at least Oneiric to use it.

Comment: I use ubuntu 12.04. I edited the question, thanks.

Comment: Can you try `sudo apt-get remove nvidia-current nvida-current-updates nvidia-settings` from terminal followed by `sudo mv /usr/X11/xorg.conf /usr/X11/xorg.conf.nvidia.old` and see what happens. You will need to `reboot`. This should drop you back to the nouveau drivers. If that works, you can try to reinstall the `nvidia-current-updates` driver from **Additional Hardware**. Let me know how it pans out.

Comment: I've tried it already, but nothing changed. Everything is exactly the same.

Comment: That's too bad. Do you have `/etc/modprobe.d/nvidia-current-updates_hybrid.conf` or `/etc/modprobe.d/nvidia-graphics-drivers.conf` or anything similare in `/etc/modprobe.d` that could be blacklisting **nouveau**?

Comment: Also, you may try `apt-get purge` instead of remove in the command above. This is a *Hail Mary*, admittedly.

Comment: If I may ask, what changed to make nouveau work? When you installed the nVidia Driver, did you install `nvidia-current` or `nvidia-current-updates`?

Comment: I think there was something wrong with ~/.config/monitors.xml, but I'm not sure. I've tried both `nvidia-current` and `nvidia-current-updates` and both of them caused 'no signal' message from monitor.

Comment: I' glad that it is at least working. You could use [this ppa](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-x-swat/+archive/x-updates) then install `nvidia-graphics-drivers` if you want to try the newest stable drivers (295.53). It may cause the same problems, but it may work. Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

Select the default ubuntu kernel (usually the top one), and rather than pressing enter, press E to edit.

Press DOWN ARROW until you get to the line that starts with

```
linux /boot
```

and press END keys to position your cursor at the end of the that line usually ending with “quiet splash”.

Now type in the additional kernel option `nomodeset` (please dont make the same typing error I made for this screenshot :-)

[image: Nomodeset]

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't help.

Comment: What is the `nomodeset` option supposed to do? I have a somewhat similar issue and I'm looking for alternative solutions (see [Nvidia X Server flickers, hangs and segfaults on start-up](http://askubuntu.com/questions/400044/nvidia-x-server-flickers-hangs-and-segfaults-on-start-up)).